# Background flicker problem in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, internet-explorer-7, background-image, flicker

I have several pages with a background image applied to the `body` of each one of them (same background image for all pages).

When I go from one page to another it looks like IE7 renders the image again, which looks like flickering.

In Firefox 3.6.3 it does not flicker.

How this flickering can be solved for IE ?

Comment: better yet, you could post an url...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE's caching of CSS background images basically sucks. There is a microsoft filter for your CSS that should fix it (proprietary, of course, so you may want to disguise it in a conditional comment):

html {
  filter: expression(document.execCommand("BackgroundImageCache", false, true));
}